# how do I compress all files within a folder on Unix?

Tags: unix

I've been unable to compress the contents of a folder on Unix, note that I don't want to compress the directory itself but the contents inside.

so far.. to compresss the files I use:

```
compress /serv/test/file.sas7dbt
```

Lets say I want to compress all files in the folder test, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you need to use compress or would `tar -cZ` work?

Comment: Consider carefully whether you really want to use `compress`.  That's a very old compression program (it produces `.Z` files, if that refreshes anyone's memory).  Typical Linux systems don't even have it, though I think `gzip` can uncompress `compress`ed files.  Newer and better compression programs include `gzip` and `bzip2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use bzip2:

```
for file in /serv/test/*; do
    bzip2 -k $file
done
```

The `-k` option keeps the original file.

With compress, the loop would be really close.

If you can use `tar`, it will create a single file archive instead of multiple files.

EDIT: as gman pointed out, the `find` utility can be used to compress instead of doing a for loop:

```
find /serv/test/ -type f -exec bzip2 -k {} \;
```

Comment: It's really only compressing files separately that is the key. You could also use a `find /path/ -type f -exec bzip2 ....` to achieve the same result. You can also use the compression utility of your choice: zip/gzip/etc.

Comment: Yup, forgot about `find` :)